# how to design a stack of monad transformers for my compiler frontend

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, monads

I'm working on a Haskell version of the assignments in Modern Compiler implementation in ML. I currently have a working front end and IR translation module, but they are using some very bad hacks which I want to avoid.

The hacks are mainly global IORefs created through `unsafePerformIO`. Those global IORefs are used to implement the `symbol` module described in the book.

`symbol` is a light-weight representation for a String. They way the module works is is basically by keeping track of a `Map` and an `Int`. For each string that I have not yet seen before assign it the next integer, and modify the stored map and counter in the `IORef`.

`symbol` module is used by the parser and the IR translation module. The parser uses it to translate `String` into `symbol`s, while IR uses another module that's based upon the `symbol` module to create unique function labels (the language I'm implementing supports nested function declarations).

Now, I would really like to get rid of the `IORef`s and `unsafePerformIO`s. So I was thinking I can use `StateT (Map, Int) ParsecT [Token] () m` instead so that the map and counter is kept inside a state monad. While the computation for IR translation will be kept inside the inner monad `m`.

But this doesn't really work, because I'd like to be able to still use combinators like `try`, `optionMaybe` from the `Parsec` library.

In short, the imperative analogy is that I have a module `A`, whose functionality is accessed by two other modules `B` and `C` (could be more). `A` itself needs to keep track of some states, and `B, C` might or might not perform stateful computations. How would one translate such a relationship into Haskell?

I would love to hear some advice on how to structure code and how to design a stack of monads for this kind of problem. I am very new to Haskell, and if these ideas don't seem to make sense, please let me know and tell me what the right way to do things is :)

Comment: "But this doesn't really work ..." Why not? It would seem that keeping things inside of IO or some other monad is the simplest thing to do. You can certainly still use functions from Parsec. Can you give some example code for the type of thing you'd want to do, or your existing solution using `unsafePerformIO`?

Comment: I think I might be confusing myself a little bit. Let's say `type Frontend = StateT (Map, Int) ParsecT [Token] () m`. So when I write the parser, because I need to access the `symbol` feature, the signature of the parsers would have to be `Frontend ty` right? But for combinators like `<|>` they seem to require the two arguments to be of type `ParsecT ...`.

Comment: Right now I have stuff like this

    `symbolState :: IORef (SymbolMap, Int)
    {-# NOINLINE symbolState #-}
    symbolState = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef (Map.empty, 0)

    symbol :: String -> IO Symbol
    symbol str = ...`

Comment: Hmm actually I think I might have realized what's happening. First of all, I needed to import Control.Applicative for <|> since StateT is an instance of Alternative. But the problems with `try`, `optionMaybe` and `between` combinators from `Parsec` are still unsolved. `lift` from `MonadTrans` class lifts a monad, but these combinators are functions that takes monads and produce new monads. So How would I "lift" them into the `StateT (Map, Int) ParsecT [Token] () m` monad?

Comment: Why not have `ParsecT` on the outside? Or why not move  the state into the `u` "user state" param in `ParsecT`?

Comment: BTW, [`trifecta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta) with [`parsers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers) allows you to add transformers on either sides freely, as the basic combinators there require only an `Alternative` constraint or are factored out in other classes. With `StateT s (ParsecT st u m) a` we have to manually write wrapping/unwrapping code for the combinators.

Comment: Having `ParsecT` on the outside would indeed work... It just felt a little weird to me because a lot of the stuff on this stack is not really parsing related, so I wasn't sure if I should do that.